# Autovacuum and partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, vacuum, autovacuum

Postgres doc tells that partitioned tables are not processed by autovacuum. But still I see that `last_autovacuum` column from `pg_stat_user_tables` is populated with recent timestamps for live partitions.

Does it mean that these timestamps are set by the background worker which only prevents transaction ID wraparound, without actually performing ANALYZE&VACUUM? Or whatever else could populate them?

Besides, taken that partitions are large and active enough, should I run the both ANALYZE and VACUUM manually on those partitions? If yes, does the order matter?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to elaborate, thanks to the comments given.

1. Taking that vacuum should work the same way on partition as on the regular table, what could be a reason for much faster growth of the occupied disk space after partitioning? Before partitioning it was nearly a linear function of records count.
2. What is confusing as well, when looking for autovacuum processes running I see that those related to partitions are denoted with "to prevent wraparound", while others are not. Is it absolutely a coincidence or there is something to check?
3. Documentation describes partitioned table as rather a virtual entity, without its own storage. What is the point in denoting that it is not vacuumed?

Comment: Where did you find that information? Every table will be vacuumed when there is a need for

Comment: @FrankHeikens, right here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html Partitioned tables are not processed by autovacuum. Statistics should be collected by running a manual ANALYZE when it is first populated, and again whenever the distribution of data in its partitions changes significantly.

Comment: The partitions are vacuumed and analyzed as usual.  It is the parent table alone that is not.

Comment: A partition is vacuumed when data has changed, when there is a need for. It’s not done because of a vacuum on the parent. These are different tables. And yes, one could be a parent and the other a child

Comment: @FrankHeikens , thanks a lot for your comments. May I ask you to take a look at the update above?

Comment: @jjanes thanks a lot for your comments. May I ask you to take a look at the update above?

Comment: For number 2 we need way more information, and number 3 is the opposite of what I can find in the documentation

Comment: @FrankHeikens, a quote from the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html): The partitioned table itself is a “virtual” table having no storage of its own. Instead, the storage belongs to partitions, which are otherwise-ordinary tables associated with the partitioned table.

Comment: The parent table is empty, is virtual. But still needs a vacuum once and a while to avoid the wrap around. auto vacuum takes care of this. The partitions will be vacuumed more often, when data has changed. But, what problem do you try to solve?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, the (1), much faster growth of the disk space occupied, compared to the non-partitioned version.

Comment: Then you should ask a question about that issue and give us some information

Comment: Which partition is growing?  All of them?  Use [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html) to see if there is a lot of dead space or free space.  Maybe someone adopted partitioning in anticipation of a major increase in activity, and now that increase has happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement from the documentation is true, but misleading. Autovacuum does not process the partitioned table itself, but it processes the partitions, which are regular PostgreSQL tables. So dead tuples get removed, the visibility map gets updated, and so on. In short, there is nothing to worry about as far as vacuuming is concerned. Remember that the partitioned table itself does not hold any data!

What the documentation warns you about is `ANALYZE`. Autovacuum also launches automatic `ANALYZE` jobs to collect accurate table statistics. This will be work fine on the partitions, but there are no table statistics collected on the partitioned table itself, so you have to run `ANALYZE` manually on the partitioned table to get these data. In practice, I find that not to be a problem, since the optimizer generates plans for each individual partition anyway, and there it has accurate statistics.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a chance to correct/complete that part of the doc? I'm quite sure that all of my colleagues have read it the same way, i.e. wrong.

Comment: I suggested a [documentation patch](https://postgr.es/m/1fd81ddc7710a154834030133c6fea41e55c8efb.camel%40cybertec.at).